# Liferay: Marking the Address field in Organizations as required

Tags: liferay

By default, when creating an organization, only the Name field is marked as required. How can I modify the Organization creation process by marking the Address field as required also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the Liferay user guide (http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/configuring-liferay-s-properties) and specifically http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/organizations, there is a way to set a field as mandatory.

Setting

```
organizations.country.enabled[regular-organization]=true
organizations.country.required[regular-organization]=true
```

marks the field as required even there is no indication in the UI that this field is mandatory. Also, the check is performed server-side and not using JavaScript as it is for other fields. Either ways, the check is performed.